# I assert an error cannot happen in Java. How do I code that?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  outputStream.write(signature.getR());
  outputStream.write(signature.getS());
  outputStream.write(signature.getV());
} catch (java.io.IOException exception) {
  // WHAT GOES HERE?      
}
```

The Java documentation tells me that this `ByteArrayOutputStream` might throw an `IOException`. And so the compiler requires me to put this in a `try`/`catch` block.

Based on the fact that I am concatenating only about 100 bytes, and I am not closing the stream in the meantime, I do not expect any errors.

Or more clearly, I don't want to handle or pass of any errors.

In Swift I would do this with an assertion (`try!`).

In Java how do I make it so that an exception here results in the program terminating and does not require me to bubble up exceptions the whole way?

Comment: Wrap it in an unchecked exception, like `RuntimeException` and throw the unchecked exception. That should cause the program to terminate. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: What Abra said, and you should consider putting a print statement in there to indicate what went wrong where.  The last thing you want to find out when debugging an error is that it's untraceable because you didn't print anything because you thought it would never happen.  Better to be safe than sorry, a print statement is just a one-liner.

Comment: "*... Or more clearly, I don't want to handle or pass of any errors. ...*" - This is not possible in Java. Java follows the [Catch or Specify Idiom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html): either we catch an exception, or we declare that the block of code (method) throws that exception. The only exception (pun intended) are `RuntimeException`s. But they should be used knowingly and intentionally, not as a reflex.

Comment: it's a checked exception and you are forced to handle it, one solution is to rethrow runtime exception, so you program fails (if you want it to fail), or add checked exception to your method signature and handle it higher.

Comment: Or more clearly, I don't want to handle or pass of any errors. << if this is a goal you can ignore the exception like this `catch (java.io.IOException ignore)` giving variable the ignore name. but as guys adviced better to throw the runtime exception (thats noth a best practice either) or follow the rules `The Catch or Specify Requirement` P.S i'm prety sure on `ByteArrayOutputStream` compiler will not force you to handle exception because write method in that class never throws it

Comment: `RuntimeException` is exactly what I was looking, it is semantically equivalent to `try!`. And I am happy that I can put some words in there. And I do appreciate that `RuntimeException` is different than normal exceptions that I should bubble up. Thank you!

Comment: Put an `assert` in the catch block?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken, Basically Throwable at the top of hierarchy with Exception, Error as primary next level. `RuntimeException` is a special `Exception` that shares similarity with `Error`. I tried to add more details as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Invalid/Inconsistent/Unexpected scenarios

1. Checked Exceptions - expected and caller should be aware (runtime course correction)
2. Unchecked Exceptions - unexpected and caller need not take course correction (back to coding, fix and redeploy)

### Checked Exceptions

1. Possible invalid state of operation where the immediate caller can take a course correction
2. Or else propagate such exception up in call hierarchy by adding to `throws`
3. Or turn into a Unchecked exception due to this being an unacceptable state due to bug and decide on caller's decision
4. Silently consume(catch) and proceed as though nothing happened

#### Why IO operations are generally `Checked`?

1. The IO(network) could be unavailable temporarily so that caller can retry
2. IO(File) permission might be incorrect and hence caller can try an alternate action (different path or change permissions if allowed)
3. Insufficient resource(space) and the caller can free up some resource and retry
4. Invalid path and hence write to different path (or create the path)

### Unchecked Exceptions

1. Invalid states which should not happen at runtime (say NPE)
2. Unexpected states like Stack overflow Error, Out of memory error (though caller can course correct by taking an alternate action like unreferencing to GC large objects or call iterative logic instead of recursive logic). These actions should be decided by developer at compile time and should not be generally handled at runtime.

### Java states

1. Throwable - any invalid state - Unchecked
2. Exception - primarily predicted invalid states (unpredicted too with RuntimeException) - Checked for everyone except RuntimeException hierarchy
3. RuntimeException - a special type of Exception for unpredicted or should not happen or no alternative - Unchecked
4. Error - abnormal and could not handle - Unchecked

### Assuming the call is for `write(int)`, it is safe to ignore for this specific use case

ByteArrayOutputStream.write(int) will not throw checked exception
There is no checked exception defined for `.write(int)` [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write(int))

But the parent class [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)) has checked exception.

So, `catch` block can be left empty or its not even required unless you are using the OutStream as the reference to hold the ByteArrayOutputStream object

The following code works perfectly fine in JDK 11 compiler and runtime

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.write(65);
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
```

It can throw NPE for null input (technically this is unboxing error)

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Integer input = null;
        b.write(input);
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
```

### If its write(byte[]), then `OutputStream.write` throws checked exception and hence it has to be caught.

But it can throw other runtime exceptions too.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            b.write((byte[])null); // NPE
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (java.io.IOException exception) {
  throw new UncheckedIOException(exception);     
}
```

One of the reasons for introducing [UncheckedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) in Java 8 was to hide the abuse of `IOException` in Java, and shut the compiler up. Very useful for lambdas that can't throw checked exceptions.